# Green's theorem via Stokes's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I am considering the following form of Stokes's theorem:

Let $\omega$ be an $n-1$ differential form with compact support on an oriented manifold of dimension $n$. Let us consider the boundary $\partial M$ of $M$ with the induced orientation. Then
$$\int_{M}d\omega = \int_{\partial M}\omega.$$

In Green's theorem we have a positively oriented, piecewise smooth, simple closed curve $C$ in a plane, and $D$ be the region bounded by $C$. So $C$ plays the role of $\partial M$ and $D$ of $M$.

On the other hand in Stokes's theorem the boundary $\partial M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n-1$.

My question is the following: is there a way to deduce Green's theorem from Stokes's theorem?

Comment: In what form would you like Green's theorem?

Comment: For a simple closed curve $C$ which is piecewise smooth but not necessarily smooth.

Comment: So $\int_D \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} \right) \, dx \, dy = \int_C ( L \, dx + M \, dy )$?

Comment: Yes but it seems to me that in Stokes theorem (at least the version I wrote in the question)  the boundary $\partial M$ which in this case is $C$ should be smooth

Comment: Ah, that you can deal with by taking a smooth approximation to it (basically, round off the corners), then take the limit. (And since we're doing integrals, everything'll work, much like it works for the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, Stokes's Theorem holds fine for manifolds with corners.